# Include external html to a Twig template in Drupal 8

Tags: theming, 8

Hi I need to include some external html code to be included as part of a template. 
I tried by using twig include:

```
{% include 'http://external-url' %}
```

but Drupal launches the following error:

```
Twig_Error_Loader: Template "http://external-url" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "http://external-url" in the Drupal theme registry.)
```

I used to have:

```
{% include directory ~'/partials/header.html.twig' %}
```

where header.html.twig contained the necessary html. But as that html will be updated by third parties, I need to include from external url.

Any way to do that? Maybe I could add the url to the Drupal 8 RegistryLoader some way?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this warranted a downvote.  While not Twig related, I have had a somewhat similar siutation where I needed a template from a trusted external source.

Comment: just like any include, you can alternatively paste the code instead.

Comment: Ssweat, there is no option to just past the code on a twig file and go, as I pointed this file will be mantained and updated by third parties, and should be always included from url.